# Rails ActiveRecord :select with specific order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query like this

```
order_id = 4
Order.find(order_id, :select => 'orders.root_id, orders.lft, orders.rgt').attributes
```

which returns something like

```
{"lft" => 1, "rgt" => 10, "root_id" => 9}
```

and need an array in this order: root_id, lft, rgt. Any tips anyone?

Comment: `{"lft" => 1, "rgt" => 10, "root_id" => 9}` is a Hash do you want it to be Array?

Comment: Yap, I'd need [9, 1, 10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attrs =Order.find(order_id, :select => 'orders.root_id, orders.lft, orders.rgt').attributes
array = [attrs['root_id'], attrs['lft'], attrs['rgt']]
```

that way?

Answer (score 2):

The easy button here is to do the conversion yourself, since you're dealing with a single record:

```
order_array = [order.root_id, order.lft, order.rgt]
```

The larger question is probably "Why?", and the answer is likely that you're Doing It Wrong™.

Answer (score 1):

```
Order.find(order_id, 
           :select => 'orders.root_id, orders.lft, orders.rgt').attributes
          .values_at("root_id", "lft", "rgt")
```

Answer (score 0):

For ordering you can apply `sort`  method for result.

```
h = {"lft" => 1, "rgt" => 10, "root_id" => 9}
h.sort { |x,y| y <=> x }
=> [["root_id", 9], ["rgt", 10], ["lft", 1]]


Order.find(order_id, :select => 'orders.root_id, orders.lft, orders.rgt').attributes.sort { |x,y| y <=> x }
```